# Format print value as percentage in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this code:

```
if SPEED <= 0.0129:
    seqSpeed = (SPEED / 100.0) * 15.5
    print("Speed: {:1.0%}".format(seqSpeed))
```

Instead of showing `Speed: 20%`

It shows `Speed: 1%%%`

What can I do to fix it?

Comment: It works for me. All I notice is an extra unmatched bracket on the print line.

Comment: I think you calculation is wrong. That does not look like a percentage. Can you give us more details about your input and expected output? What is `SPEED` supposed to be to obtain `20%`?

Comment: To get a percentage you *multiply* by 100, you don't divide.

Comment: Pretty sure it should be `print("Speed: {:1.0f}%".format(seqSpeed))`, with the `%` outside the braces.

Comment: @WilliamMiller, `%` is a valid specifier: `Percentage. Multiplies the number by 100 and displays in fixed ('f') format, followed by a percent sign.`

Comment: @Barmar I know I multiply by 100 to get a percentage. What I'm trying to do here is expressing the SPEED which is 0.0129 as 20%. This is a part of a function where SPEED values are changeable it goes from 100% to 20% descending order

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `%` specifier multiplies the value by a hundred then acts as if you'd used the `f` specifier.

Since your maximum `SPEED` here is `0.0129` (as per the `if` statement), your formula `(SPEED / 100.0) * 15.5` will generate, at most, `0.0019995`. The `%` specifier will then turn that into `0.19995`, which is only about `0.2%`.

If you're expecting it to give you `20%`, you need to get rid of the `/ 100.0` bit from your formula. That way, you'll end up with `0.19995`, the `%` specifier will change that to `19.995`, and you should then get `20%` by virtue of the fact you're using `1.0` as the width specification, as per the following transcript:

```
>>> SPEED = 0.0129
>>> seqSpeed = SPEED * 15.5
>>> print("Speed: {:1.0%}".format(seqSpeed))
Speed: 20%
```

Answer (score 0):

Use f-strings instead:

```
if SPEED <= 0.0129:
    seqSpeed = (SPEED / 100.0) * 15.5
    print(f'Speed: {seqSpeed}')
```

And if you need to use `.format()`:

```
print('Speed: {0}'.format(seqSpeed))
```

And also there is:

```
print('Speed: %s' % x)
```

Comment: Okay, while that's generally good advice assuming you're on 3.6+, how does that fix the problem stated by the asker? It also won't format in the desired manner.

Comment: Not really, you've added two *other* things that also don't format to `1.0`. While I'm not *convinced* the asker is getting the results they state with the code they have, you haven't really explained why using a different formatted-print method is going to fix their problem. In fact, it will simply output the value with a default format, and not do the multiply-by-100 that the `%` specifier gives in the question.

Comment: actually it's unclear to me whether the problem is calculating the percentage or displaying it so I won't bother explaining something that might be irrelevant to what he asked, anyway it's up to him to decide whether this does solve the problem or does not.